# requests не может зайти на сайт

Tags: python, requests

Пытаюсь спарсить один сайт, но requests никак не хочет на него заходить, при том на остальные заходит отлично, не могу понять в чем проблема.
Код и какую выдало ошибку ниже.

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.mtg.ru/'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.status_code)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 268, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 489, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 268, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\parsing.py", line 4, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 701, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Алексей\PycharmProjects\MTG_base\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 547, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение` — неужели эта фраза требует перевода на какой-нибудь другой язык?

Comment: Вероятно, проблема в том, что сайт запрещает подключаться к себе из requests

Comment: Сервер знает что запрос выполнен не из браузера.

Comment: вопрос скорее в том, почему он разорвал соединение и как можно подключиться по-другому

Comment: Подсмотреть заголовки, которые передаёт браузер, и прописать в скрипте такие же. Может поможет, может нет. Для начала можно через какой-нибудь `fakeuseragent` заголовки нагенерить, авось прокатит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте заголовки и юзер агент в будем вам счастье

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.mtg.ru/'
headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) Все заработало

Comment: да не за что)
можно разные заголовки использовать, в сети полно их

Comment: @AleksandrFetisov зачем их брать из сети, если можно брать из своего собственного браузера? Особенно если брать такие старые заголовки — для сайта это будет верным признаком бота, потому что реальные люди с настолько старым браузером уже давно не сидят